# How to remove dead SQL Server registrations from SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager?

Tags: sql-server, database

We had some databases decommissioned recently, and my SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager still shows the server group I originally created containing those servers.  I tried deleting the entire server group, but Enterprise Manager won't let me do so because the group still contains server registrations.  When I right-click on individual server registrations to try and delete them one-by-one, Enterprise Manager tries to connect to the server and complains when it can't.  I don't get to see the option to delete the server registration.

So ... how can I work around that and get these dead server registrations out of my Enterprise Manager configuration?  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my test setup here, once the server connection times out (30 seconds), you can right click again and the menu will appear up. It only happens when you don't move the mouse to another server after clicking the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!  I also since found the registry key where these server registrations are stored:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\SQLEW\Registered Servers X

Comment: This does not seem to be valid for never SQL Server installations

Comment: @HansLindgren Newer versions of SQL Server don't have a "SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager" tool. If you're wondering about a similar issue but with SSMS included in newer versions of MSSQL, perhaps post a new question. This one is specific to SQL Server 2000.